# Solution of $(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}=\frac{1}{12}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Solve the given equation for $n$

$(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}=\frac{1}{12}$

How to approach this particular question? Sorry cannot show any work because the only approach I can see is take cube on both sides but that is complicating the equation.

Comment: Hint: adding $n^{1/3}$ to both sides then taking cubes on both sides will give you a quadratic equation for $n^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=\sqrt[3]{n+1}$ and $y=\sqrt[3]{n}$. Note that $(x-y)^3=x^3-y^3-3xy(x-y)=1-3xy(x-y)$. So
$$\frac{1}{12^3}=1-\frac{xy}{4}.$$
Solve for $xy$. We get $xy=a$, where $a$ is a mildly messy number.

We also have $x-y=b$, where $b=\frac{1}{12}$.

So $(x+y)^2=b^2+4a$, and now we know that $x+y=\pm\sqrt{b^2+4a}$.

We know $x+y$ and $x-y$, so we know $y$. Finally, $n=y^3$.

*Remark*: The strategy used here is the one that Cardano used to find the roots of a reduced cubic.

Answer (score 1):

At least from what I see, we may have to complicate the question..
$$(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}=\frac{1}{12}$$
$$\sqrt[3]{n+1}\cdot12-\sqrt[3]{n}\cdot12=1$$
$$\sqrt[3]{n+1}=k\Rightarrow n=k^3-1$$
$$-12\sqrt[3]{k^3-1}=1-k\cdot12$$
$$\left(-12\sqrt[3]{k^3-1}\right)^3=(1-k\cdot12)^3$$
$$-1728k^3+1728=1-36k+432k^2-1728k^3$$
$$36k-432k^2+1727=0$$
$$k=\dfrac{-36+\sqrt{36^2-4(-432)\cdot1727}}{2(-432)},k=\dfrac{-36-\sqrt{36^2-4(-432)\cdot1727}}{2(-432)}$$
$$k=-\dfrac{\sqrt{20733}-3}{72},k=\dfrac{3+\sqrt{20733}}{72}$$
Both solutions here are true after verification.
$$\sqrt[3]{n+1}=-\dfrac{\sqrt{20733}-3}{72}, \sqrt[3]{n+1}=\dfrac{3+\sqrt{20733}}{72}$$
$$373248n+373248=186624-\sqrt{20733}\cdot20760,373248n+373248=186624+\sqrt{20733}\cdot20760$$
$$n=-\dfrac{865\cdot\sqrt{20733}+7776}{15552}, n=\dfrac{865\cdot\sqrt{20733}-7776}{15552}$$
Both solutions here are also true after verification.

Comment: Why not use \cdot instead of * ?

Comment: @Olba12 Good suggestion, edited.

Answer (score 1):

As ddsLeonardo commented, rewrite $$(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}=\frac{1}{12}$$ as $$(n+1)^{1/3}=n^{1/3}+\frac{1}{12}$$ Cube both sides $$n+1=\left(n^{1/3}+\frac{1}{12}\right)^3=n+\frac{n^{2/3}}{4}+\frac{n^{1/3}}{48}+\frac{1}{1728}$$ Simplify to get $$n^{2/3}+\frac{n^{1/3}}{12}-\frac{1727}{432}=0$$ Define $x=n^{1/3}$ to get the quadratic $$x^2+\frac{x}{12}-\frac{1727}{432}=0$$ Solve for $x$ and then $n=x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
The equation we have involves differentiation of one function of $n$. That function is $f(n)=n^{\frac{1}{3}}$

According to the definition of differentiation:-
$$f'(n)=\frac{f(n+h)-f(n)}{h}=\frac{(n+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}-n^{\frac{1}{3}}}{1}=\frac{1}{12}$$

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but shouldn't you use $\lim_{h \to 0}$? On the other side if you want to use derivatives what you've writen reminds me of MVT, but then we get that $\exists c \in (n,n+1)$ s.t. $f'(c) = \frac{1}{12}$, which isn't much helpful in this case.

Comment: That's why i have given only hint because it may lead somebody to the solution.